# Intuitive but hard question about an integral?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Let $f \colon [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function with continuous derivative such that $f(1)=1$. Evaluate $$\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}\int_0^1yx^yf(x)dx$$

Comment: have you tried to proceede with the change of variable $z = x^{y+1}$ ?

Comment: I tried so, but then i have something like $f(z^{\frac{1}{y+1}})$. Is there any good way to deal with it? Thank you!

Comment: Well, the problem says that $f$ is differentiable, so maybe try integrating $\int_0^1 1\cdot f(z^{1/(y+1)})\,dz$ by parts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\fermi\pars{1} = 1}$.

> $\large\tt\mbox{Heuristically !!!}:$

\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\lim_{y\ \to\ \infty}\int_{0}^{1}yx^{y}\fermi\pars{x}\,\dd x}
=\lim_{y\ \to\ \infty}\int_{0}^{1}y\pars{1 - x}^{y}\fermi\pars{1 - x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm]&=\lim_{y\ \to\ \infty}\int_{0}^{1}
y\exp\pars{y\ln\pars{1 - x} + \ln\pars{\fermi\pars{1 - x}}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm]&=\lim_{y\ \to\ \infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}
y\exp\pars{-yx - \fermi'\pars{1}x}\,\dd x
=\lim_{y\ \to\ \infty}{y \over y + \fermi'\pars{1}}=\color{#66f}{\LARGE 1}
\end{align}

Comment: This is nice !!! :)

Answer (score 4):

All you need is that $f$ is continuous with $f(1) = 1$.  Note that
for any $\delta \in (0,1)$,

$$\int_0^{1-\delta} y x^y\; dx = \dfrac{y}{y+1} (1-\delta)^{y+1} \to 0$$

while

$$ \int_0^1 y x^y\; dx = \dfrac{y}{y+1}\to 1$$

Take $\delta$ so that $|f(x) - f(1)| < \epsilon$ for $1-\delta < x \le 1$, and
use the fact that $f$ is bounded...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't see how to obtain the conclusion...

Comment: What can you conclude about the integral from $0$ to $1-\delta$?  About the integral from $1-\delta$ to $1$?

Comment: Oh sorry, I have seen it now. Thank you ;)